# How to use SVM in Weka?

Tags: java, weka, libsvm

I'm trying to use the svm classifier in weka. When I click on the libsvm classifier and try to train a model based on some provided training data, I get the error

```
libsvm classes not in CLASSPATH.
```

The weka website has some information on how to fix this but I'm not sure how to execute them.

http://weka.wikispaces.com/LibSVM

I got the libsvm.jar file from the link provided. I'm not sure which file to put it in.

Comment: The SVM algorithm for weka is: `weka.classifiers.functions.libsvm`

Answer (score 2):

You have to set your classpath variable so it knows where to find that jar on your local machine.

If you are on windows right-click computer->properties->advanced system settings->environment variables and set it under system variables. Chances are you already have a classpath variable; so just add the path of your jar file to the end.

Reference: http://weka.wikispaces.com/CLASSPATH

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Rob's answer: suit your values as below. This is how it is saved for me.

- Variable Name: CLASSPATH
- Variable value: C:\Program Files (x86)\Weka-3-6\libsvm-3.20\java\libsvm.jar

Answer (score 0):

You just need Libsvm.jar in the class path with latest versions of weka. Just try it like this

```
WekaPackageManager.loadPackages( false, true, false );
AbstractClassifier classifier = ( AbstractClassifier ) Class.forName(
        "weka.classifiers.functions.LibSVM" ).newInstance();
```

If you prefer to give options set the options like this

```
String options = ( "-S 0 -K 0 -D 3 -G 0.0 -R 0.0 -N 0.5 -M 40.0 -C 1.0 -E 0.001 -P 0.1" );
String[] optionsArray = options.split( " " );
classifier.setOptions( optionsArray );
```

Finally train the classifier

```
classifier.buildClassifier( train );
```

Answer (score 0):

In your .bash_profile file or in your environment variables you need to append the full path to the libsvm jar file
For a .basch_profile file:
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/FULL_PATH_TO_LIBSVM.jar